# Slow `statistics` functions

Tags: python, statistics

Why is `statistics.mean()` so slow compared to the NumPy version or even to a naive implementation like e.g.:

```
def mean(items):
    return sum(items) / len(items)
```

On my system, I get the following timings:

```
import numpy as np
import statistics

ll_int = [x for x in range(100_000)]

%timeit statistics.mean(ll_int)
# 42 ms ± 408 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit sum(ll_int) / len(ll_int)
# 460 µs ± 5.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit np.mean(ll_int)
# 4.62 ms ± 38.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


ll_float = [x / 10 for x in range(100_000)]

%timeit statistics.mean(ll_float)
# 56.7 ms ± 879 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit sum(ll_float) / len(ll_float)
# 459 µs ± 7.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit np.mean(ll_float)
# 2.7 ms ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I get similar timings for other functions like `variance` or `stdev`.

EDIT:
Even an iterative implementation like this:

```
def next_mean(value, mean_, num):
    return (num * mean_ + value) / (num + 1)

def imean(items, mean_=0.0):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        mean_ = next_mean(item, mean_, i)
    return mean_
```

seems to be faster:

```
%timeit imean(ll_int)
# 16.6 ms ± 62.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit imean(ll_float)
# 16.2 ms ± 429 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [statistics module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) uses interpreted Python code, but `numpy` is using optimized compiled code for all of its heavy lifting, so it would be surprising if `numpy` didn't blow `statistics` out  of the water.

Furthermore, statistics is designed to play nice with modules like [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) and [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html) and uses code which values numerical accuracy and type safety over speed. Your naive implementation uses `sum`. The statistics module uses its own function called `_sum` internally. [Looking at its source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/statistics.py) shows that it does an awful lot more than just add things together:

```
def _sum(data, start=0):
    """_sum(data [, start]) -> (type, sum, count)
    Return a high-precision sum of the given numeric data as a fraction,
    together with the type to be converted to and the count of items.
    If optional argument ``start`` is given, it is added to the total.
    If ``data`` is empty, ``start`` (defaulting to 0) is returned.
    Examples
    --------
    >>> _sum([3, 2.25, 4.5, -0.5, 1.0], 0.75)
    (<class 'float'>, Fraction(11, 1), 5)
    Some sources of round-off error will be avoided:
    # Built-in sum returns zero.
    >>> _sum([1e50, 1, -1e50] * 1000)
    (<class 'float'>, Fraction(1000, 1), 3000)
    Fractions and Decimals are also supported:
    >>> from fractions import Fraction as F
    >>> _sum([F(2, 3), F(7, 5), F(1, 4), F(5, 6)])
    (<class 'fractions.Fraction'>, Fraction(63, 20), 4)
    >>> from decimal import Decimal as D
    >>> data = [D("0.1375"), D("0.2108"), D("0.3061"), D("0.0419")]
    >>> _sum(data)
    (<class 'decimal.Decimal'>, Fraction(6963, 10000), 4)
    Mixed types are currently treated as an error, except that int is
    allowed.
    """
    count = 0
    n, d = _exact_ratio(start)
    partials = {d: n}
    partials_get = partials.get
    T = _coerce(int, type(start))
    for typ, values in groupby(data, type):
        T = _coerce(T, typ)  # or raise TypeError
        for n,d in map(_exact_ratio, values):
            count += 1
            partials[d] = partials_get(d, 0) + n
    if None in partials:
        # The sum will be a NAN or INF. We can ignore all the finite
        # partials, and just look at this special one.
        total = partials[None]
        assert not _isfinite(total)
    else:
        # Sum all the partial sums using builtin sum.
        # FIXME is this faster if we sum them in order of the denominator?
        total = sum(Fraction(n, d) for d, n in sorted(partials.items()))
return (T, total, count)
```

The most surprising thing about this code is that it converts the data to fractions so as to minimize round-off error. There is no reason to expect that code like this would be as quick as a simple `sum(nums)/len(nums)` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is indeed an awful lot more code, for allegedly greater accuracy. Yet I do not see how this is meant to be more accurate than `sum(nums)/len(nums)`. Unless I am missing something really obvious here, for `int` this is close to irrelevant, given the arbitrary integer support in Python. For `float`/`complex` almost the same, the error is at most a bunch of bits. And if one is just obsessed with accuracy, it would be wiser to explicitly convert to `decimal`s before averaging. I don't know about others, but my take home message is to shy away from `statistics`.

Comment: @norok2 The  [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/) for the statistics module is interesting. It gives their rationale for their `sum`. Maybe with `pandas` now, there is less motivation for this module. While the accuracy might be overkill, consider Excel. Their first generation of statistics functions were mathematically correct but handled round-off error poorly, in a way that made a difference in some use-cases. That is why Excel now has two versions of every stats function. The original for backwards compatibility, and a new and improved one which is more numerically stable.

Answer (score 2):

The developer of the statistics module made an [explicit decision](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/#id59) to value correctness over speed:

> Correctness over speed. It is easier to speed up a correct but slow function than to correct a fast but buggy one.

and moreover [stated](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/#id71) that there was no intention to

> to replace, or even compete directly with, numpy

However, a [enhancement request](https://bugs.python.org/issue35904) was raised to add an additional, faster, simpler implementation, [statistics.fmean](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/statistics.html#statistics.fmean), and this function will be released in Python 3.8.  According to the enhancement developer this function is up to 500 times faster than the existing `statistics.mean`.

The `fmean` [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9d062d690b768252204992fc6ab7c3873a87442d/Lib/statistics.py#L305) is pretty much `sum/len`.

Comment: I don't think that "bug" is a good word for the current `mean`, but `fmean` sounds like it will be a welcome addition.

Comment: @JohnColeman fair point, I've changed to "enhancement" - thanks!